# Where is master process located in cluster architecture of nodejs app?

Tags: node.js

Let's say, I've got a 4-core CPU, which basically means, my computer could run 4 processes at the same time; no more no less.
Now let's look at cluster module of nodejs; there are

- 1 master process
- 4 worker processes

Can I say, each worker process is to be assigned to each core of the CPU?
And if it is, then where is its master process located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The master process is fired as a standard single-thread process (or service) so it "is assigned to" and lives on one of your CPU cores (or threads, depending on the case).

Each worker process is then spawned (`forked`) as described in the docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

---

Just so you know, Node now supports the use of `worker_threads` to execute JavaScript in parallel on multiple threads, so it's technically not true anymore that Node is limited by single-thread execution:

https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: So it also means that a master process and one of the worker processes resides together inside any core, correct?